# Show TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

From my MainViewController I would like to show/present a UITabBarController that I have created with the first (most left) UIViewController. How do I Do that?

The UITabBarController is created inside the Storyboard.

Comment: Use segue to present the tabBarController

Comment: What do you mean by "first (most left) UIViewController"?